# Spark DataFrame - how to convert single column into multiple row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Need to convert single row into multiple columns. Did below things.

```
val list = List("a", "b", "c", "d")

  import spark.implicits._

  val df = list.toDF("id")

  df.show()

  import spark.implicits._

   val transpose = list.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (_, index) => col("data").getItem(index).as(s"col_${index}")
  }

  df.select(collect_list($"id").as("data")).select(transpose: _*).show()
```

output:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_0|col_1|col_2|col_3|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|    b|    c|    d|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Did something and convert it. But problem with transpose function, it is relaying original data (list). If we do any filter in df, it will always shows 4 column as original list have 4. How can i shortout this list.

### Adding more info

```
df.filter($"id" =!="a" ).select(collect_list($"id").as("data")).select(transpose: _*).show()\
```

if apply filter condition and show command

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_0|col_1|col_2|col_3|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    b|    c|    d| null|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

which is wrong and should show 3 columns not 4 columns.

Comment: can you post sample expected ouput ?

Comment: Same output but looking for best/another approach.

Comment: Do I understand correctly you are looking for a flattening function? If so, a project called Hermes has one [here](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/hermes/blob/develop/utils/src/main/scala/za/co/absa/hermes/utils/HelperFunctions.scala#L129). Not the cleanest code, but will flatten anything. You just need to cherry pick your usecase. If there is more need for it, we can move it to the [absa commons](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/commons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it with pivot :

```
val df = List("a", "b", "c", "d").toDF("id")

val dfFiltered = df.filter($"id"=!="a")

dfFiltered
  .groupBy().pivot($"id").agg(first($"id"))
  .toDF((0 until dfFiltered.count().toInt).map(i => s"col_$i"):_*)
  .show()

+-----+-----+-----+
|col_0|col_1|col_2|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    b|    c|    d|
+-----+-----+-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Did some trick with trimming the columns based on df row count.
Let me know if it helps

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object TransposeV2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    val list = List("a", "b", "c", "d")

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = list.toDF("id")

    df.show()

    import spark.implicits._

    val transpose = list.zipWithIndex.map {
      case (_, index) => {
        col("data").getItem(index).as(s"col_${index}")
      }
    }

    df.select(collect_list($"id").as("data")).select(transpose: _*).show()

    val dfInterim = df.filter($"id" =!="a" )
    val finalElements : Int = dfInterim.count().toInt
    dfInterim.select(collect_list($"id").as("data")).select(transpose.take(finalElements): _*).show()
  }

}
```

Comment: I think , the above code will NOT work. as expected.. Because we filtered "a" at the position 1 if we take using count and .take - then it will include first nth element..